# how asynchronous servlet processing improve performance

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, asynchronous

I read from http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets012.htm

> Java EE provides asynchronous processing support for servlets and filters. If a servlet or a filter reaches a potentially blocking operation when processing a request, it can assign the operation to an asynchronous execution context and return the thread associated with the request immediately to the container without generating a response. The blocking operation completes in the asynchronous execution context in a **different thread**, which can generate a response or dispatch the request to another servlet.

I am wondering where is the

> **different thread**

come from?     Assuming the container has 10 threads, 5 of them are processing request, we have to use another 5 to process the long running business logic?. where do we get the performance improvement? the total threads available to use is limited, right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read more about  [Servlet 3 0 final-spec - Section 2.3.3.3 - Asynchronous processing](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1402086108_ca39447ee6d3413ebcfabc35a7550c14) where it is explained in detail.

It causes the container to dispatch a thread, possibly from a **managed thread pool**, to run the specified `Runnable`. `AsyncContext` is a standard way defined in *Servlet 3.0 specification* to handle HTTP requests *asynchronously*.

> *Basically HTTP request is no longer tied to an HTTP thread*, allowing us to handle it later, possibly using fewer threads. It turned out that the specification provides an API to handle asynchronous threads in a *different thread pool out of the box*.

---

Read more about [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) that creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.

Please have a look at [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to read more about it along with sample code.

Comment: does it mean http thread is not as efficient as ExcutorService. is that the reason why we need handle the work from http thread to ExcutorService?

Comment: Can we simply increase the number of http threads? why we need create more thread inside a thread?

Comment: There is a limit of http threads that's why creates more threads from inside the http thread. Do you know what is purpose of using multiple thread inside a thread?

Comment: as far as I know, for a particular program, we have a main thread to start with, which is a entry point of that program, then inside that main thread we can ask for more threads from the jvm to run the code simultaneously.

Comment: but for container managed threads situation, if we ask more threads to handle the work(say business logic), is it possible that container will give threads which were supposed to handle the http request? Or the http thread pool and worker thread pool are seperated pool?

Comment: yes they are separate pool. I don't have any detailed context on it. Just read the specification that I shared you that will give you a correct picture of this topic.