# JSP Servlet Multithreading Qustion

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, servlets, thread-safety

I have a Servlet which gets a request from a client, then the Servlet gathers data from 5 different Servers via http request/response (every Server needs 1sec to respond) and sends the data back to the client.

The Problem is that it is too long when the Client has to wait 6 seconds for the response.
So the 5 requests to the 5 Servers must be sent at the same time.

Ideas:

1. Multithreading in the Servlet, like in a normal Java Application.
2. An own Servlet for every Server(request), so that 1 main servlet says to the 5 Gather Servlets "get the data xy" and the gather Servlets send the data to the main servlet and the main servlet back to the client.

The Problem i fear about is, that a thread/servlet gets the response from an another request because its the same time and same ip.

How to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: "The Problem i fear is, that a thread/servlet gets the respons from an another request because its the same time and same ip."--can you elaborate this

Answer (score 2):

> Multithreading in the Servlet

You can use [ServletRequest#startAsync()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#startAsync%28%29) method that puts this request into asynchronous mode, and initializes its AsyncContext with the original (unwrapped) ServletRequest and ServletResponse objects.

Read more about  [Servlet 3 0 final-spec - Section 2.3.3.3 - Asynchronous processing](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1402086108_ca39447ee6d3413ebcfabc35a7550c14) where it is explained in detail.

`AsyncContext` is a standard way defined in *Servlet 3.0 specification* to handle HTTP requests *asynchronously*.

---

Read more about [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) that creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most nThreads threads will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.

Please have a look at [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to read more about it along with sample code.

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089968/how-asynchronous-servlet-processing-improve-performance/24090162#24090162)

Comment: Do you habe a small example for me? For example i have in the doGet method: 1. String a = method1(); 2. String b = method2();. I want to process 1. And 2. Async AG the same time

Comment: Find it [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3)

Comment: THX, but i didnt get it. In all examples a long running task get outsourced in a New thread and send back to client. But i have 5 tasks i just want to run at the same time and gather all the data in one the servlet, process and send back to client.